# how to delete Meteor app.. simply remove directory?

Tags: meteor

quick question, I think. If I want to delete an app that I created with $> meteor create myapp; do I just remove the myapp directory?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just remove the directory.  Meteor stores everything in a .meteor folder under your app's directory.

**EDIT**: that's not entirely true, Meteor also has a local cache of packages you've installed (so it doesn't have to fetch them later).  This usually goes to your home folder and works in much the same way as npm.  But it's not necessary to delete this in order to remove the meteor application, they are unrelated.

Comment: Could those packages potentially stay there (and fill up the hard drive)? Does Meteor have any purging mechanism for unused packages?

Comment: Not that I know of, so yes, theoretically.  But unless you install an incredible amount of packages, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Well, if you're like me and you use a single box for development, and you start a new meteor project every other day for learning purposes over the course of two years, yeah that local cache gets pretty stupid large.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cloud 9 service (c9.io) you can create a meteor workspace with whatever npm/Atomoshphere packages that you normally work with, then clone it as a starting point for a new project. Your concerns and other peoples opinions are rendered moot.